# what does context mean in blender

Tags: modeling, node-editor, color

"In compositing and texture context each node supports the Alpha channel. In the texture context only RGB color space is available. In the shading context of the Blender internal adds HSV and the Cycles shading context offers an additional pair of nodes to combine/separate a vector (XYZ)"

trying to figure out what separate xyz node does but I don't get the meaning of 'context' in modeling

Comment: Context in this case is roughly analogous to "area" or "mode". The separate XYZ node takes a vector and separates it into 3 scalar x, y, and z values. It can be handy if you want to take object position (for example) and use just the  Z channel to shade an object with some sort of vertical gradient.